# C# - HTTP request to get the initial page

Tags: c#, http, get

I have to Send HTTP request to GET the initial page then, GET the HTTP response and do a check to see if it is a 200 response code. All this has to be saved into a .csv file, four times per website. 
This is how far I got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HTTPrequestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lstWebSites = new List<string>
            {
                "www.mearstransportation.com",
                "www.amazon.com",
                "www.ebay.com",
                "www.att.com",
                "www.verizon.com",
                "www.sprint.com",
                "www.centurylink.com",
                "www.yahoo.com"
            };
            string filename = @"RequestLog.txt";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                {
                    foreach (string website in lstWebSites)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            MyWebRequest request = new MyWebRequest();
                            request.Request();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I still have to do the GET request in another class I created called MyWebRequest.cs
Please help me.

Comment: Does `MyWebRequest` inherit `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` or `System.Net.WebRequest`?

Comment: Its using System.Net.HTTPWebRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MyWebRequest class do the following (you will also need to pass the website url string to the MyWebRequest, but I'll just do it explicitly):

```
    HttpWebResponse response = null;

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/thisisadeadlink");
        request.Method = "GET";

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Console.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            Console.Write("Errorcode: {0}", (int)response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Error: {0}", e.Status);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
    }
```

This should catch if server failed and response.StatusCode is not 200.

Comment: So where you have google.com can I just have lstWebSites and have it go through my list of websites?

Comment: Well yes, you'll need to iterate through your list and run this in a function of some sort for each URL string.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `MyWebRequest` is using `HttpWebRequest`, the `Request` method can return `HttpWebResponse` if it has the URL as a parameter like this:

```
public class MyWebRequest 
{
    public HttpWebResponse Request(string url)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // Handle exception
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

and it can be called in the `for` loop like this:

```
HttpWebResponse response = request.Request("http://" + website);
if ((response != null) && (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK))
{
    // Write .csv file
}
```